# Solving an equation set while finding the coordinates of 3rd corner of a triangle

Tags: geometry, systems-of-equations, triangles

I have an ABC triangle and I know A corner coordinates $(A_x,A_y)$ and B corner coordinates $(B_x,B_y)$. In addition I know AC side (side b) length and also BC side (side a) length of the triangel. I want to calculate C corner coordinates $(C_x,C_y)$.

I tried to use the technic about distance of two points in $2D$ space. $$
L^2=(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2$$
 as follows.

Step 1:
$$|AC|^2=(A_x-C_x)^2+(A_y-C_y)^2\\
|BC|^2=(B_x-C_x)^2+(B_y-C_y)^2
$$

Step 2: 
$$|AC|^2=A_x^2-2A_xC_x+C_x^2+A_y^2-2A_yC_y+C_y^2 \\
|BC|^2=B_x^2-2B_xC_x+C_x^2+B_y^2-2B_yC_y+C_y^2
$$

Step 3: multiply by -1 second equation
$$|AC|^2=A_x^2-2A_xC_x+C_x^2+A_y^2-2A_yC_y+C_y^2\\
-|BC|^2=-B_x^2+2B_xC_x-C_x^2-B_y^2+2B_yC_y-C_y^2$$

Step 4: Sum of two equations
$$|AC|^2-|BC|^2=A_x^2-B_x^2-2A_xC_x+2B_xC_x+A_y^2-B_y^2-2A_yC_y+2B_yC_y+C_y^2$$

I am stuck at this point because I can't leave alone $C_x$ or $C_y$ to substitute it at the other equation.

How can I solve this and find $C_x,C_y$ coordinates which represents 3rd coordinates of the triangle?

I have found similar questions in this forum but all of them was using the 0 (zero) value at least one or two known coordinates. For example $A_x$=0, $A_y$=5 and $B_x$=3, $B_y$=0 etc. In such a case the technic above turns into simpler to solve but in my case I am stuck.
Thanks in advance?

Comment: I just spent a bunch of time editing your math using LaTeX to make it more readable, using LaTeX, and you rolled back my edits. Sigh.

Comment: Thank you Jonh. I noticed that it is unreadible as soon as I submited it. It was at very good condition when I was writing but I have no idea why it is collapsed when I submited. I have no idea what is LaTex because I am very very new in this form and trying to underttand how to use it. Thanks for your kind help again.

Comment: How to format things for Math,stackexchage: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I've polished things up a bit to make them more readable; you can look at the question (click "edit") to see how I did it.

Comment: You’ve made an error in subtracting the second equation from the first. There should not be a $C_y^2$ term; you should end up with a linear equation in $C_x$ and $C_y$. The two (in general) possible solutions lie on this line.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It should not be there. I put it by mistake. But it is not the issue. I convert one of the equations in step 1 to something like $C_x$=........ or  $C_y$=........ If you convert it to $C_x$= then $C_y$ should not be at right side of the equation or if you convert it to $C_y$= then $C_x$ should not be at the right side of the equation. My math level is not enough to do that and also my technical english level is not skilled well so I hope I could  explain what I am trying to do. It seemed easy at  first but I saw that it is beyond my level.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you **don't** know is $C_x$ and $C_y$.  Try using just $x$ and $y$ for these so you can see more easily what you are trying to solve for.